# Micronaut serverless application run & debug with GCP background and cloud event function

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, micronaut, micronautgcp

[image]

I have the above architecture, where I have created three functions

1. HTTP function - for HTTP trigger
2. Background function - PubSub trigger
3. Cloud Event function - for cloud storage trigger

All the functions are in Micronaut applications

**HTTP function**

This is a regular micronaut application with `@Controller("/")` annotation

```
@Controller("/")
public record FileUploadController(IFileUploadClient iFileUploadClient){}
```

For this project, I can run simply by changing the `runtime("google_function")` to  `runtime("netty")` in the `build.gradle` file

**Question**

*Background function*

```
    public class Function extends GoogleFunctionInitializer
        implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {

    @Inject LoggingService loggingService;

    @Override
    public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) {
        loggingService.logMessage(message);
    }
}
```

*Cloud Event function*

```
public class Function extends GoogleCloudEventsFunction<StorageObjectData> {

    @Inject StorageService storageService;

    @Override
    protected void accept(@NonNull CloudEventContext context,
                          @Nullable StorageObjectData data) throws Exception {
        storageService.handleFileEvent(data);
    }
}
```

How do I run and debug the *Background function* &  *Cloud Event function* locally, how can I test it? How to trigger PubSub.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you user the Function Framework. Because of that, you can run your function locally and test/debug it.

You can follow the GitHub page instruction [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-java)